# Spring Reactive Security: adding `SecurityWebFilterChain` causes 500 error for AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

Note that I am using Spring security 5.7.4.

I have a `RestController`:

```java
@RestController
public class StandardController {
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public Mono<Map<String, String>> hello() {
        final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("hi", "hi");
        return Mono.just(map);
    }

}
```

and a `Security Config`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        User.UserBuilder userBuilder = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
        UserDetails rob = userBuilder.username("rob")
                .password("rob")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        UserDetails admin = userBuilder.username("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("USER","ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(rob, admin);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine until I try to disable `CSRF` by adding `SecurityWebFilterChain` to my security config.

```java
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
       return http
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .build();
    }


 /// ... user details service
}
```

Now, when I try to hit any endpoint UNAUTHENTICATED (including ones unaffected by CSRF like the `hello` GET route) I get the following stack trace:

```
2022-12-13T21:50:04.846-06:00 DEBUG 70978 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [1b6ff9fc-2] HTTP GET "/hello"
2022-12-13T21:50:04.851-06:00 DEBUG 70978 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.w.s.s.DefaultWebSessionManager       : Created new WebSession.
2022-12-13T21:50:04.852-06:00 DEBUG 70978 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/logout', method=POST}
2022-12-13T21:50:04.852-06:00 DEBUG 70978 --- [     parallel-2] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'GET /hello' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
2022-12-13T21:50:04.852-06:00 DEBUG 70978 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : No matches found
2022-12-13T21:50:04.853-06:00 DEBUG 70978 --- [     parallel-2] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : [1b6ff9fc-2] Mapped to com.example.demo.StandardController#hello()
2022-12-13T21:50:04.856-06:00 DEBUG 70978 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.w.r.r.m.a.ResponseBodyResultHandler  : [1b6ff9fc-2] Using 'application/json' given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/x-ndjson, text/event-stream]
2022-12-13T21:50:04.856-06:00 DEBUG 70978 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.w.r.r.m.a.ResponseBodyResultHandler  : [1b6ff9fc-2] 0..1 [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>]
2022-12-13T21:50:04.856-06:00 DEBUG 70978 --- [     parallel-2] ebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext found in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@4f4ffd93'
2022-12-13T21:50:04.858-06:00 DEBUG 70978 --- [     parallel-2] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [1b6ff9fc-2] Resolved [AccessDeniedException: Access Denied] for HTTP GET /hello
2022-12-13T21:50:04.859-06:00 ERROR 70978 --- [     parallel-2] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [1b6ff9fc-2]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/hello"

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.ReactiveAuthorizationManager.lambda$verify$0(ReactiveAuthorizationManager.java:53) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.example.demo.StandardController#hello() [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/hello" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.security.authorization.ReactiveAuthorizationManager.lambda$verify$0(ReactiveAuthorizationManager.java:53) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4444) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:350) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:246) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:305) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2508) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:291) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2034) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:250) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:324) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:155) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1802) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime.subscribeOrReturn(MonoCacheTime.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:224) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2508) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.request(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:98) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:360) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2304) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2178) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:265) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1988) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilter.java:85) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4444) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFromMonoOperator.subscribe(FluxFromMonoOperator.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDeferContextual.subscribe(FluxDeferContextual.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2508) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onSubscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:192) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:189) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4444) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2508) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2268) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2304) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2178) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4444) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4444) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:940) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2510) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2304) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2178) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4444) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:846) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:465) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:277) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:294) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:230) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2034) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:275) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1803) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onNext(MonoCacheTime.java:354) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(MonoPublishOn.java:181) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2022-12-13T21:50:04.863-06:00 DEBUG 70978 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonEncoder  : [1b6ff9fc-2] Encoding [{timestamp=Tue Dec 13 21:50:04 CST 2022, path=/hello, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, reque (truncated)...]
2022-12-13T21:50:04.870-06:00 DEBUG 70978 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [1b6ff9fc-2] Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

If I hit the endpoint authenticated, I get the valid response. Is there some mapper I am missing to map this 500 error to a 403 or similar?

Comment: Access denied is not a 500 and why would you want a 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY?

Comment: @Toerktumlare right - access denied should not cause a 500, it should case a 403. Sorry about accidentally saying 301 I got my status code mixed up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now a known bug; please check for updates here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12374